# How to call a function after UIWebView shouldStartLoadingWithRequest method call is finished?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, delegates, uiwebviewdelegate

How to call a function after `UIWebView` `shouldStartLoadingWithRequest` method is finished executing in iOS?

I dont want to use `performselector:afterdelay` because that may not give accurate result while network is low.

Comment: then use webview delegate method

Comment: use the delegate method `webviewDidFinished`

Answer (score 1):

use these methods may be it helps you,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
       return YES;
    }


    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
      //this method will call after successful loading
    }


    - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
      //this method will call after getting any error while loading the web view.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `webViewDidFinishLoad:` this method is call after a web view finishes loading.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

**Parameters**

- **webView**:
  The web view has finished loading.
- **Availability**
  Available in `iOS 2.0` and later.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIWebViewDelegate Protocol` provides a few methods which can be used in your situation.

The first method that is called after `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is `webViewDidStartLoad:` which, like its name suggests, is called once the `WebView` has started loading a frame. 
From your question, this seems to be the most adequate method.

Other options, which were provided in previous answers, are `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` which are respectively called every time the `UIWebView` finished loading a frame and whenever it fails to load a frame.

Note that this means that all methods described above may get called more than once before the `UIWebView` has actually finished loading, since they are thrown whenever the `UIWebView` is about to start, has just started, has finished or has failed loading **each frame on a page.**

Refer to the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more detailed information.